# Find minimum value in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose we have a python dictionary that stores grades with respect to roll numbers.
dict = {1:90,2:40,3:98}. If we use min(dict) then the output will be 1. How can we find the least marks out of the group(in this case 40). Also can we find the index of the returned value?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `key` argument of `min`:

```
d = {1: 90, 2: 40, 3: 98}
lowest = min(d, key=d.get)

print(lowest, d[lowest])
# 2 40
```

Another way:

```
lowest = min(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

print(lowest)
# (2, 40)
```

Comment: Please try to tone down the duplicate answering. If you see basic questions like these, they've likely already been asked. Search out duplicates before answering.